# Finding largest element in matrix B, better than O(n)? Practice Tech Interview

Tags: algorithm

Suppose we have a matrix B, size n by n, with  distinct integer elements. A local maximum exists if it is greater than all of its neighbors (diagnols too). Suppose B has exactly one local maximum and each column of B has a local maximum. Show that we can find the local maximum of B in better than O(n).

My attempt: I imagine the line "suppose B has exactly one local maximum" is meant to tell me something about the positioning (ordering?) of the elements, but I can seem to grasp my head around it. The fact that better than O(n) is a constraint tells me peak finding with divide and conquer ( O(logn*logn) ?) is a good approach, but I am not sure what to recurse upon.

Comment: I don't know the solution, but maybe you also need to use the fact that these are "**distinct** integer elements."

Comment: I'm confused by your use of 'local'. I assume that B has one _global_ maximum and each column has a _local_ maximum.

Comment: Is the O(n) correct? I mean the obvious algorithm is to go trough the matrix and store the biggest element would be O(n^2).

Comment: Can you confirmed that your question is about finding one global maximum and each column has only one local maximum?

Comment: @Kyle "each column of B has a local maximum" - does it mean at least one or exactly one?

Comment: "Suppose B has exactly one local maximum and each column of B has a local maximum." Am I the only one feel this sentence is dumb or what?

Answer (score -1):

I think it can be done in O(n).

See question says that their is only 1 global maximum (i.e 1 local maximum for whole matrix) and each column has a local maximum.

1. Start from first column and find out the local maximum(say at (i,j)). Check if it is the global maximum or not.
2. If it is not a global maximum then their has to be a local maximum in the next column in adjacent cells((i,j+1),(i-1,j+1) & (i+1,j+1) if these cells exist) which is greater than current local maximum.

Now repeat these steps and in each steps you will find local maximum for next column in constant time( you only need to compare three cells as specified in step 2) and maximum no. of columns needed to be searched = n(worst case global maximum is found in the last column).

So, total complexity is O(n).

Comment: On the second step what if (i-1,j+1) & (i+1,j+1) both are column-local maxima?

Comment: It is specified by you in the question that a column has a local maximum and not more than two local maxima , but if that is the case you will have to consider both and then it cannot be solved in O(n) complexity.

Comment: In that case for each column their will be O(n^2) comparisons i.e. 2 comparison(among three adjacent cells (for second column) maximum number of maxima could be 2 because only b/w adjacent cells only one maxima could occur)+ 3 for third column(among 5 cells maximum no. of maxima could be 3)+4+5+......+n=O(n^2)